# Rails: form_for active record object complaining about no index path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I have a survey model that has no index page. I only want an edit view for this model, but it seems like rails wont let me do that. It complains `undefined method surveys_path` when I try to use `form_for(@survey)`. Is there anyway around doing this without creating an empty index route/view.

Here is my survey controller so far

```
class SurveysController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @survey = Survey.find(params[:id])

  end

  def edit
    @survey = Survey.new
    job = Job.find(params[:id])
    @survey.job_id = job.id
    authorized_user = job.user
    unless !is_runner?(current_login) && current_login.id == authorized_user.id
        redirect_to jobs_path
    end
  end

  def update
    @survey = Survey.new(params[:survey])

  end

end
```

And here is the form partial being rendered in the edit.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@survey) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :speed %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :speed %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :service %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :service %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :suggestion %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :suggestion %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: can you try this: `form_for @survey, :url => survey_path(@post), :method => :put do...` ?

Comment: Im getting this error `No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"surveys", :id=>nil}`

Comment: Would you kindly post your routes?

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't be asking about `surveys_path` just for defining a form, but there are some oddities in your controller code that could be causing you grief.

1. Your edit action should, in the surveys controller of a RESTful app, be using that params[:id] to find an existing survey, why is it finding a job? It should be doing the same as your show action.
2. Your survey object in the survey edit method is new and unsaved, therefore the form builder will generate a form pointing to a create action rather than an update action. Form builder will generate an edit form only for records that are [`persisted?`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-persisted-3F)

Have you defined the routes for this model? You should have something like the following in your routes file:

```
resources :surveys, :except => [:index] # will create all rest routes for survey model except for an index route.
```

Answer (score 0):

You get this error if you mistakenly run your model/table as plural instead of singular. You probably ran something like this:

```
rails generate model surveys
```

Instead of this:

```
rails generate model survey
```

So, if you run:

```
rake routes
```

You'll probably see that all of your routes have an 's' ie. surveys_new.

So, rails is confused. You need to rename your table in a migration.

```
class ChangePluralNametoSingularforSurveys< ActiveRecord:Migration
  def change
    rename_table :surveys, :survey
  end 
end
```

Then you'll have to rename your files (surveys.rb, etc) manually.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the issue was nested routes. If your object has a parent and its routes are nested, you'll need to do something like:

```
<%= form_for([@category, @survey]) do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```